# Is Unloading DLL done before making free static memory?

Tags: c++, dll

Can anyone help me with this. We are working on an issue and I am missing this concept.

A function creates a static object of a class[A] in which an other class object gets created, when an user exits the application all the windows get destroyed and then at the last system function at exit() will be called to cleanup global data which calls the destructor of A.

My question is will the dll's be unloaded after the destructor of A is called or even before that?

Comment: What does "windows memory free" mean? What does "static memory free" mean? And why do you think that "static memory free" and "unloading DLL" are distinct events?

Comment: You probably want to explain what the actual issue is.

Comment: I mean the static memory will be released at the last point in the reverse order of allocation so will the dll's unloading be the last operation when exiting an application or releasing the static memory?

Comment: Are you referring to the ordering for destructors of static objects running and the DLL getting unloaded?

Comment: i updated the post with actual issue.

Comment: It depends :). There are many sub cases:  Is the DLL statically linked? Are the two classes in the same DLL? Do you have cyclic dependencies between objects from different DLL's? It is surprisingly easy to end up with random crashes at application exit.

Comment: They are not in the same dll and there is no cyclic dependencies between objects.

Comment: How is the DLL loaded - implicitly or explicitly? Is it explicitly unloaded? Are the static objects defined in one of the DLLs or in the EXE?

Answer (score 1):

In C++ DLL or shared object, objects declared as file-static or class-static instances are allocated their base storage within the DLL image itself. So the memory will be released when the DLL is unloaded.

This is not true of any memory allocated to hold heap-allocated members of those objects, for example if you have a static object like this:

```
struct B {
    basic_string <char> s1;
    B(char*x){s1 = basic_string<char>(x);
    static B b_inst("test");
}
```

Static object `B::b_inst` is allocated within the DLL. The original C string `"test"` passed in is allocated in the DLL. But the storage allocated by `basic_string` to hold the copy of `"test"` is allocated on the heap.

So when does that get cleaned up?

Well, just BEFORE the dll is unloaded, the system calls the DLL's entrypoint (known as DllMain). This in fact is supplied by the CRT (if you write one, yours is called by the CRT supplied one, which runs code both before and after). The job of the CRT DllMain is to call the static constructors and destructors, and constructors and destructors of static objects.

So as long as your DLL is unloaded gracefully, and DllMain runs happily with no errors/access violations etc, they should get cleaned up correctly.

Comment: But my issue was the dll's were unloaded already before the static object destructor was called, so can you tell me the possible cause for this?

Comment: How did you figure that was the case?

Comment: @user1767288, do you mean the object A was created by the DLL or are these other DLLs which are nothing to do with object A?